# Upgrading from Groovy 1.3.5 to 1.7.5

Tags: groovy

I've just inherited an application written in Groovy (version 1.3.5) and would like to upgrade it to the newest release (version 1.7.5).

I can't seem to find a reference that enumerates the differences in syntax, etc., which I would need to be aware of ... and yes, I looked at http://groovy.codehaus.org

Does anyone know of a good place that lists version changes?

Many thanks,

~Aki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the changes from one version to another by looking at the release notes. However, the release notes only describe the changes from version N to version N + 1. I don't know how many versions there were between 1.3.5 and 1.7.5, but I'd guess at least 10.

To discover all the changes between 1.3.5 and 1.7.5, you'll have to look at the release notes for each release. Starting from [this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download), you should be able to find them all, here are some links to get you started.

[1.7.5](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10242&version=16639)

[1.7.4](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10242&version=16563)

[1.6.9](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10242&version=16236)

[1.6.8](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10242&version=16019)

[1.5.8](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10242&version=14630)

You should be able to get older releases (and their notes) from the [distribution archive](http://dist.groovy.codehaus.org/distributions).

Having said all that, reading release notes doesn't guarantee anything, (though it's a good way to learn about new features). The only way to be sure that your code runs under the newest version is to compile and test it under that version.

Comment: Thank you Don.  I've been away from hands on development for a long time - and I've never really taken the release notes path ... this is new to me.  It'll be an exercise - well worth it, to get a glimpse into Groovy that I perhaps would not have had a chance to get.

Thanks again,
~Aki

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to try it and see where your tests fail.

You do have tests right? ;-)

If not, I'd write some, then try the upgrade and fix where needed.

I don't believe there is a single page where you'd find all the changes from one version to another.

You could maybe collate something by going through all the release notes, but it's probably quicker to just try it.

Comment: Hi Tim - thanks for your response. I'd vote your answer up (and I tried), but I don't have enough reputation points to do so.  I'm just getting back into development and though I've been a member for 18 months or so, I have not really used (or contributed to) the stackoverflow community very much at all.  This will change. But again, thank you for your response. No silver bullet. Like almost anything else in the dev world :)